# Is there a way to ignoreCase in javaScript (Discord Bot Development)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a swear filter for my discord bot, however, obviously, depending on the case of the message, it does not always get deleted. I'm not entirely sure how to use ignoreCase in JS, or if it even a thing, but if anyone could help me here that would be terrific!

Here is my code (I have censored the swear words because I have no clue I'm allowed to post that content here):

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.channel.type !== 'dm') {
    if (msg.author.id !== "760491381034319883")
        if (msg.channel.id !== '777030418230149140')
            if (msg.content.includes("swearword") ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword2")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword3")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword4")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword5")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword6")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword7")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword8")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword9")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword10")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword11")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword12")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword13")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword14")) ||
                (msg.content.includes("swearword15"))) {
                msg.delete(msg)
```

So if there is a way to make those swear words exempt case, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words instead to filter profanity

```
const Filter = require('bad-words');
const filter = new Filter();
 
if (filter.isProfane(msg)) msg.delete(msg);
```

Comment: I actually don't know but they probably do some sort of machine learning like analyzing a trillion text messages and flagging the ones that have profanity.

Comment: Oh, so does it already know the swear words, or I need to add them in?

Comment: No it already knows the swear words and has a list of them pre set but you can add  extra if you want to.

Comment: Do you know how to add more, or is it in the documentation that you linked?

Comment: It is in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The includes method itself is always case sensitive. However, rather than doing a case insensitive comparison, you could just lowercase the msg itself and compare against that. You can read about the toLowerCase method here: [mozilla toLowerCase() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

```
msg.content.toLowerCase().includes("swearword")
```

If you really do want to do a case insensitive match you can consider using the match method. The match method takes a regular expression which in the case of case insensitive matching is just "i". Look here for more information: [mozilla match() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
msg.content.match(/swearword/i);
```

You might also want to consider an alternative to chaining the long "||" statement such as using a dictionary.

Comment: I think if I wanna use toLowerCase() it has to be msg.content.toLowerCase().includes('swearword') right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var words = ["hello", "bay"]; // array of words
if(words.some(word => message.content.includes(word))){
    console.log("Welcome to the matrix")
}
```